# Two speeds of precession without nutation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes, precession

I understand mathematically that when you look for solutions to the equations of motion of a spinning symmetric top with a constant inclination angle $\theta$, you get a quadratic equation with two solutions implying a slow and a fast rate of precession.  But in the course of trying to explain this to students, I've realized I don't fully understand in a *physical* sense how you get one or the other.  Is it just a matter of different initial conditions?  I've seen statements to the effect that the slower precession is most often observed without fully understanding how you would start one or the other.
As a follow-up, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a video demonstrating both modes.  I've been unable to find any by searching.